# Is there a way to use abilities at my mouse cursor when I press the hotbar button?

Tags: titan-quest-anniversary-edition

I've been playing Titan Quest Anniversary Edition. I've had a lot of fun, but I'm encountering an a problem I always had with the game - targeting abilities feels clunky. I have to hit the button, and then click a target. That stinks.

Is there a way to streamline this? I looked over the options briefly and didn't see anything.

Comment: Just as an aside, I think this is called smart casting, at least in league

Comment: There are mods that do this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in-game. You'll have to use a third-party program (AutoHotkey, AutoIT) to do that.

Here's an AutoHotkey script, taken from [the official Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/475150/discussions/0/343788552539940197/#c343788552542765325):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance
#InstallKeybdHook
#InstallMouseHook

SetTimer, MoveTimer, 128

return

MoveTimer:
IfWinActive, Titan Quest
  {
      GetKeyState, state, MButton ; or what button you want it to be
      if state = D
      {
         MouseClick, left
      }
      GetKeyState, state, numpad0 ; or what button you want it to be
      if state = D
      {
    ;MouseClick, left
      }
  }
return
```